# Getting exact match with Elastic Search 6 and php ClientBuilder

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I'm building an elasticsearch powered layered navigation module for an ecomm site.  It's all working great, I can fetch the options from my external source and display them.   Selecting them works too but I've run into a snag where one of the filter options has these choices;

```
FINISHES:

Finished (1)

Semi-Finished (16)

Semi Finished (1)
```

Clearly the 2 variations with and without a hyphen should be tidied up, but ignoring that for a moment, when I apply the following to my collection;

```
$client = $this->clientBuilder;
$params .... etc
$params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][] = ['match_phrase' => [$split[0] => "$selected"]];
$response = $client->search($params);
```

Where $split[0] is the elasticsearch field ref for 'FINISHES' and $selected is the chosen value.  If you click on any of the options, I am getting all 18 records back.  No doubt because they all contain one of the words being searched 'finished'.

How can make this search for the exact term only?  I've tried escaping the hyphen with \- which didnt help, I've also tried checking whether the searched term has spaces or hyphens and trying to forcibly add them to 'must_not', but that didn't work either;

```
if(!$space) {
    $params['body']['query']['bool']['must_not'][] = ['match' => [$split[0] => ' ']];
}
if(!$hyphen) {
    $params['body']['query']['bool']['must_not'][] = ['match' => [$split[0] => '\\-']];
}
```

Comment: Is you field analyzed? if not, the standard analyzer will skip the hyphens while indexing. Did you try the search using `.keyword`?

Comment: all fields are standard, we will want to use them for fuzzy search in other contexts, it's only for layered search we want to return literal 100% match results.  How does .keyword work?

Comment: `.keyword` searches against original text i.e. non-analyzed. by default standard analyzer is applied to all fields. So in your case, `Semi-Finished` is  the keyword and  the inverted index will contain two words `semi` and `finished`, so every time you look for `finished` it matches sine standard analyzer breaks it on hyphen. I dont know php code you wrote, however the syntax is `fieldname.keyword` and i'm sure that can be incorporated here.

Comment: genius!  That works perfectly - stick it in an answer and ill accept it for you.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: No Problem. I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default standard analyzer is applied to all fields. So in your case, `Semi-Finished` is the `keyword` and the inverted index will contain two words `semi` and `finished`, so every time you look for finished it matches since standard analyzer breaks it on hyphen.

```
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text": ["Semi-Finished"]
}

##Result
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "semi",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "finished",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 13,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

`.keyword` searches against original text i.e. non-analyzed.  In your case, `fieldname.keyword` should work.

```
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "keyword",
  "text": ["Semi-Finished"]
}

##Result
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "Semi-Finished",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 13,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: perfect, in php i modified it the field name like this; $field = $split[0].'.keyword'; and then called that like this; $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][] = ['match_phrase' => [$field => "$selected"]]; - problem solved